# dovecot authentication against passed-file

Tags: centos, authentication, imap

currently i am facing some issues with dovecot and authentication against a passed-file.

Here some details about the environment:

- Centos 7 (3.10.0-042stab142.1)
- postfix (2:2.10.1-9.el7)
- dovecot (1:2.2.36-6.el7)

The postfix part looks fine, sending/receiving of mails locally and forwarding to external domains is working. For the a handful users i need to enable imap capability.

Extract of "doveconf -n":

```
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
first_valid_uid = 1000

mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/<mydomain>/
mbox_write_locks = fcntl

namespace inbox { 
  inbox = yes
   location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk 
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent 
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent 
  } 
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash 
  } 
 prefix = 
 } 

passdb { 
  args = scheme=SHA512-CRYPT username_format=%Lu /etc/dovecot/mydomain_passwd 
  driver = passwd-file 
} 

service auth { 
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix 
  } 
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0666 
  }
 } 
service imap-login { 
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143 
  } 
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes 
  }
 }
ssl = required 
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain/fullchain.pem

ssl_cipher_list = ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA

ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes

userdb { 
  args = username_format=%Lu /etc/dovecot/mydomain_passwd 
  default_fields = uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/var/mail/vhosts/mydomain/%Ln 
  driver = passwd-file
}
```

content "mydomain_passwd":

```
Zelestra@mydomain:{SHA512-CRYPT}$6$69/Qa2lPaBz3q6Gy$2zL7zAsgp6JckiziPUxJc927p.YSAyQlAYCKIJ2uvA.uR6pPfktEcHO4mbnAO3LEVVYT6jNrSPykO.STuTJJH0:5000:5000::/var/mail/vhosts/mydomain/zelestra::
```

This is what i get if i try to test the user with "doveadm user ":

```
Jul  6 13:56:36 h2891775 dovecot: auth: Debug: master in: USER#0111#011zelestra#011service=doveadm
Jul  6 13:56:36 h2891775 dovecot: auth: Debug: passwd-file(zelestra): lookup: user=zelestra file=/etc/dovecot/mydomain_passwd
Jul  6 13:56:36 h2891775 dovecot: auth: passwd-file(zelestra): unknown user
Jul  6 13:56:36 h2891775 dovecot: auth: Debug: userdb out: NOTFOUND#0111
Jul  6 13:56:43 h2891775 dovecot: auth: Debug: master in: USER#0111#011zelestra@mydomain#011service=doveadm
Jul  6 13:56:43 h2891775 dovecot: auth: Debug: passwd-file(zelestra@mydomain): lookup: user=zelestra@mydomain file=/etc/dovecot/mydomain_passwd
Jul  6 13:56:43 h2891775 dovecot: auth: passwd-file(zelestra@mydomain): unknown user
Jul  6 13:56:43 h2891775 dovecot: auth: Debug: userdb out: NOTFOUND#0111
```

if i test it from a mail client (a mac built in during that test):

```
Jul  6 14:03:03 h2891775 postfix/smtpd[14258]: disconnect from tmo-081-218.customers.d1-online.com[<some IP>]
Jul  6 14:03:03 h2891775 dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#0115#011PLAIN#011service=imap#011secured#011session=5GStp8SpXxJQu1Ha#011lip=<some IP>#011rip=<some IP>#011lport=143#011rport=4703#011local_name=mail.mydomain#011resp=AFplbGVzdHJhQGtvbnppbGRlcmFzcGVrdGUuZGUARDN2MWwuM3JheQ== (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)
Jul  6 14:03:03 h2891775 dovecot: auth: Debug: passwd-file(zelestra@mydomain,<some IP>,<5GStp8SpXxJQu1Ha>): lookup: user=zelestra@mydomain file=/etc/dovecot/mydomain_passwd
Jul  6 14:03:03 h2891775 dovecot: auth: passwd-file(zelestra@mydomain,<some IP>,<5GStp8SpXxJQu1Ha>): unknown user
Jul  6 14:03:05 h2891775 dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL#0115#011user=zelestra@mydomain#011original_user=Zelestra@mydomain
Jul  6 14:03:05 h2891775 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 5 attempts in 10 secs): user=<zelestra@kmydomain>, method=PLAIN, rip=<some IP>, lip=<some IP>, TLS: Disconnected, session=<5GStp8SpXxJQu1Ha>
```

If i do a lookup like this "doveadm user *@mydomain" - i ll get this output:

```
Zelestra@mydomain
```

It seems i am missing something but at the moment i have no clue where to look or how to troubleshoot further.

Already done multiple times without luck:

- reading through he dovecot wiki/howto
- google foo and exchange foo without getting any results providing help in that variant of issue

Question i look to answer at the moment:

a) why is the wildcard lookup of doveadm getting results but a specific lookup don't

b) a hint how to get the dovecot imap part working and get an proper authentication of my client

thanks and regards

Comment: strange stackexchange removes my greetings opener from the post. Sorry for that :/

Comment: @roaima for the sake of output it is zelestra@mydomain and the file used to lookup is mydomain_passwd - i will edit the lines in the code output - so it reflects only the generic one

Comment: The password given in that output is already change to something different so it doesn't matter. A "typo" can be a misspelled word, grammatical things and or such things - sorry if you are not used to that phrase

Comment: I'm pleased to hear you'd already caught the passwords

Comment: You're authenticating zelestra@mydomain but the authentication database appears to have Zelestra@mydomain

Comment: wow - that is sad - didn't saw that before or better say i saw it but i assumed, as it was not state different in the doku - that if converting username to lowercase it would do that for the "db" as well. Any how made day thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to roaima - changing the content of my "userdb/passwd" to lower case entries it worked.

So in my case it was the "covert to lowercase" option for the userdb and the passdb - which is only converting the entered info not that existing in the database. Sadly this was not mentioned in the documentation and it is not the behavior i expected here.